# File Sharing from a Mac to a PC Issues

Tags: macos, file-sharing

I am trying to share a folder on the Mac (Leopard) to my Windows XP laptop.  I went into System Prefs, clicked on Sharing, added the folder called TwoTB and it seemed to work (more or less).  That is all it took.

Then all of a sudden, clicking on a `\\macmini\TwoTB` started asking for a password.  I tried entering my userid/password - did not work.  I tried creating a new person in the Sharing applet complete with a password.  Tried entering that on the WinXP laptop - still did not work.

Simply hitting `\\macmini` used to bring up the list of shares, now it asks for a password.

What am I missing?

Comment: For the username and password have you tried entering `\\macmini\username` instead of just your username?

Comment: Tried that approach: nothing.  Btw, not \\macmini\username, but simply macmini\username should do the trick, but it does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like guest connections got disabled.  The checkbox to reenable it is in System Preferences -> Accounts pane -> Guest Account in the sidebar -> "Allow guests to connect to shared folders".

BTW, if you want to allow non-guest access to the shared files from Windows (i.e. get it to accept the account passwords), you need to enable Windows compatability for each account in System Preferences -> Sharing pane -> File Sharing -> Options -> the list of user accounts under "Share files and folders using SMB (Windows)".

Comment: All the options you mentioned we turned on.  Still nothing.

Comment: Got it working.  I went into Sharing, then Options, then added a checkbox under my name.  Then I could log in with my name mac name.  

It still does not explain why Guest Sharing does not work, but that's for another question.

Comment: If the guest checkbox is on but you can't connect, there may be something weird in the config files; first thing to try is turning guest off & back on to see if that fixes it.  If not, and you want to dig, check the config files: /var/db/smb.conf should contain lines that say "auth methods = guest odsam" and "map to guest = Bad User"; /var/db/samba/smb.shares should contain a bunch of sections for users' public folders, each of which should include "guest ok = yes".